# How to parse JSON in Swift 2?

Tags: json, swift2

I have a PHP web api that returns json in the following format:

```
{"users":[
   {"user": {id:"1","name":"ahmad"}},
   ...

]}
```

In my Swift 2 code, I am able to retrieve the data above store it in an `NSArray` named `users`

Now, I need to iterate throw each `user` to convert it into an object:

```
for user in users {
    print("found: \(user)")
}
```

That ouputs something like:

```
found: {
    user =     {
        id = 1;
        name = ahmad;
    };
}
```

but when I try to access any element of that object I get an error:

```
let id  = user["user"]["id"]     //does not work: Xcode wont compile
let id2 = user["user"]!["id"]!   //does not work: Xcode wont compile
let id3 = user!["user"]!["id"]!  //does not work: Xcode wont compile
```

[image]
Then I tried :

```
if let u=user["user"] {     //does not work: Xcode wont compile
    // do somthing
}
```

I put a break point at `print("\(user)")` to see what is going on, and here is what I found:

[image]

When I print the description of each individual `user` I get:
[image]

How can I access the elements of this JSON data in Swift 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `NSArray` only holds `AnyObject` so you have to cast it (to `Array<Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>>>`. Below you see the shorthand):

```
// this is a forced cast and you probably get runtime errors if users cannot be casted
for user in users as! [[String : [String : String]]] {
    print("found: \(user)")
}
```

Comment: I did that. No errors but I was still not able to do something like : `let id=user["user"]!["id"]!`

Comment: Reading your answer again, I couldn't help but to think: It makes total sense to do it this way. The objects are stored like that... Thanks again

Comment: As a suggestion if it is possible you should use Swift's built in collection model (`Array`, `Dictionary`) rather than the Foundation equivalent due to its static type system.